# Editorial Design: Correct labelling of a graphic that is based on an original

Tags: publishing, editorial-design

I am working on the editorial design of an article dealing with U.S. military history. In the article I am using a graphical interpretation of an original U.S. Army insignia. The insignia is of the Ghost Army Unit of the U.S. Army during WWII. The graphic is used instead of an image of the actual insignia due the style guidelines of the entire publication the article will be a part of. However, the graphic still needs a label underneath/next to it.

My question is: How should I label it? I cannot put a label saying "Insignia of the Ghost Army Unit during WWII" because that is not true since it is a graphic modelled after the original insignia. Should I label it "Replica of the insignia of the Ghost Army Unit during WWII"? Or "Representation of the insignia of the Ghost Army Unit during WWII"?

Does anyone have some useful suggestions?

Here is an image of the original insignia as well as of the graphic used in the article:

[image: OriginalInsignia]

[image: InsigniaGraphic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could follow the language used in Copyright law and say it is "derived from ..." or "a derivatve of ..."

> A derivative work is a work based on or derived from one or more
> already existing works. Common derivative works include
> translations, musical arrangements, motion picture versions of
> literary material or plays, art reproductions,  abridgments, and
> condensations of preexisting works. Another common type  of derivative
> work is a “new edition” of a preexisting work in which the editorial
> revisions, annotations, elaborations, or other modifications
> represent, as a  whole, an original work.  To be copyrightable, a
> derivative work must incorporate some or all of a  preexisting “work”
> and add new original copyrightable authorship to that work.  The
> derivative work right is often referred to as the adaptation right.
> The following are examples of the many different types of derivative
> works:
>
> ...
> A drawing based on a photograph

See [this circular from the US Copyright Office](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ14.pdf) (PDF).